# Assigning values to every other index in an array

Tags: arrays, node.js

I have three arrays that correlate to one another (Users, Wins, and Lost), Wins[0] through Wins[2] stand for Users[0] through Users[2]. If Users[0] through Users[2] won and Users[3] as well as Users[4] lost, then Lost[3] and Lost[4] need to be equal to 1.

```js
var Users = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5"];
var Wins = ["1", "1", "1", "0", "0"];
var Lost = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]; //Lost[3] and Lost[4] need to be equal to 1
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: Setting Lost according to Wins?

Comment: if Win[3] and Win[4] are equal to 0 and Win[0] through Win[2] are equal to 1, then Lost[3] and Lost[4] need to be equal to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and a [`ternary operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to produce the `Lost` array:

```js
var Users = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5"];
var Wins = ["1", "1", "1", "0", "0"];
var Lost = Wins.map((win) => win === "1" ? "0" : "1");

console.log(Lost);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const lost = wins.map(w => w === "1" ? "0" : "1");
```